# show all products in one page on magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks, phtml, cms-block

I want to show all products in one page from a custom cms block.
This is the code I tried:

```
{{block class="\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" template="Magento_Catalog::list.phtml"}}
```

It doesn't work because the page is blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to try the below steps to show All Product in one page.

**Content -> Pages -> Show/Hide Editor -> Insert Widget -> Select Widget Type**

Further info. you need to help the below screenshot.

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5P0r.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMwLU.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YGwN.png

After Save CMS Page check on your frontend.